# Pandas row to list (only the values)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to take the values from a specific pandas row and save them to a list, but I don't get only the values. What I am doing wrong? For example i want only the first row

thanks

```
list = []
n = 10

for i in range(n):
   x = dtest.iloc[[0],i]
   list.append(x)
```

```
list 

[0    9
 Name: 0, dtype: int64, 0    6
 Name: 1, dtype: int64, 0    3
 Name: 2, dtype: int64, 0    6
 Name: 3, dtype: int64, 0    6
 Name: 4, dtype: int64, 0    0
 Name: 5, dtype: int64, 0    0
 Name: 6, dtype: int64, 0    0
 Name: 7, dtype: int64, 0    6
 Name: 8, dtype: int64, 0    9
 Name: 9, dtype: int64]
```

Comment: use `n=10` and `dtest.iloc[0].head(n).tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in method `tolist`. Try:

```
dtest.iloc[0].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
l = list(dtest.iloc[x, :])
```

where  x is the row index